# SignalR No data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, signalr

An exception of type `System.InvalidOperationException` occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Örnek hatası.

page load

```
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            List<Products> Personeller = new List<Products>();
            Personeller.Add(new Products());
            rptCustomers.DataSource = Personeller;
            rptCustomers.DataBind();

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static IEnumerable<Products> PersonelleriGetir()
        {

using (SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BaglantiProvider"].ConnectionString))
            {             
        /*      baglanti.Open();  
place of error */
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [nameid], [nameid1], [img], [nameid2], [nameid3] from [dbo].[data]", baglanti))
                {
                cmd.Notification = null;
                SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BaglantiProvider"].ConnectionString);
               SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                if (baglanti.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    baglanti.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        List<Products> Personeller = new List<Products>();
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            Personeller.Add(new Products
                            {
                              name1= Convert.ToInt32(dr["nameid"].ToString()),
                                name2= Convert.ToInt32(dr["nameid1"].ToString()),
                                name3= dr["img"].ToString(),
                                name4= Convert.ToInt32(dr["nameid2"].ToString()),
                                name5= Convert.ToInt32(dr["nameid3"].ToString())
                            });
                        }
                        return Personeller;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            LogHub.Show();
        }
    }

public class Products
{
    public int name1{ get; set; }
    public int name2{ get; set; }
    public string name3{ get; set; }
    public int name4{ get; set; }
    public int name5{ get; set; }
}
```

**output:**

> Internal Server Error
>
> 500

I couldn't make a signalr **asp.net web form** data connection.

can you please help on this issue